# Can a smart contract know its own address?

Tags: smart-contracts

Is it possible to create a smart contract that knows the value of its KT1 address?

E.g. if you wanted the contract to check that there was a signature signed over its contract address, would it be able to find it/refer to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Michelson provides the following instruction [SELF_ADDRESS](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#instr-SELF_ADDRESS)

In SmartPy you can use [`sp.self_address`](https://smartpy.io/reference.html#_contracts_and_addresses)